# How to Parse Hierarchical Data and Format it into a TSV File in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have a dataset with hierarchical information and KO numbers, and I'm looking to format this data into a TSV (Tab-Separated Values) file in Python, where the first column contains KO numbers, the second column contains descriptions, and the third column contains a hierarchy based on the nearest 'A' section in the input data. The hierarchy should include elements starting with 'A,' 'B,' and 'C' up to the nearest 'C' section. Also if same KO number is present different hirarch, that hirarchy should be seperated by | under same row
input data is file.keg formate
Input Data:

```
A09100 Metabolism
B
B  09101 Carbohydrate metabolism
C    00010 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis [PATH:ko00010]
D      K00844  HK; hexokinase [EC:2.7.1.1]
D      K12407  GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]
D      K00001  E1.1.1.1, adh; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1]
B  09103 Lipid metabolism
C    00071 Fatty acid degradation [PATH:ko00071]
D      K00001  E1.1.1.1, adh; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1]
A09120 Genetic Information Processing
B
B  09121 Transcription
C    03020 RNA polymerase [PATH:ko03020]
D      K03043  rpoB; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta [EC:2.7.7.6]
D      K13797  rpoBC; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta-beta' [EC:2.7.7.6]
```

Expected Output:

```
    KO      metadata_KEGG_Description        metadata_KEGG_Pathways
K00844  HK; hexokinase [EC:2.7.1.1]     Metabolism, Carbohydrate metabolism, Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
K12407  GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]   Metabolism, Carbohydrate metabolism, Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
K00001  E1.1.1.1, adh; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1]    Metabolism, Carbohydrate metabolism, Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis|Metabolism, Lipid metabolism, Fatty acid degradation
K03043  rpoB; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta [EC:2.7.7.6]  Genetic Information Processing, Transcription, RNA polymerase
K13797  rpoBC; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta-beta' [EC:2.7.7.6]  Genetic Information Processing, Transcription, RNA polymerase
```

I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to correctly process this data into a desired TSV file based on the provided hierarchical information. Thank you for your assistance!

this is my code

```
data = """A09100 Metabolism
B
B  09101 Carbohydrate metabolism
C    00010 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis [PATH:ko00010]
D      K00844  HK; hexokinase [EC:2.7.1.1]
D      K12407  GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]
D      K00001  E1.1.1.1, adh; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1]
B  09103 Lipid metabolism
C    00071 Fatty acid degradation [PATH:ko00071]
D      K00001  E1.1.1.1, adh; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1]
A09120 Genetic Information Processing
B
B  09121 Transcription
C    03020 RNA polymerase [PATH:ko03020]
D      K03043  rpoB; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta [EC:2.7.7.6]
D      K13797  rpoBC; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta-beta' [EC:2.7.7.6]"""


lines = data.split('\n')

result = []

ko = None
description = None
hierarchy_names = []

for line in lines:
    parts = line.strip().split()
    if parts:
        if parts[0].startswith('A'):
            # Reset hierarchy for a new 'A' section
            hierarchy_names = [" ".join(parts[1:])]
        elif parts[0] == 'K':
            ko = parts[0]
            description = " ".join(parts[1:])
        elif parts[0] == 'D' and len(parts) >= 3:
            ko = parts[1]
            description = " ".join(parts[2:])
        else:
            hierarchy_names.append(" ".join(parts[1:]))

    if ko and description:
        hierarchy_str = ", ".join(hierarchy_names)
        result.append([ko, description, hierarchy_str])

# Add the header row
result.insert(0, ["KO", "metadata_KEGG_Description", "metadata_KEGG_Pathways"])

# Specify the filename for the TSV file
tsv_filename = "output_data.tsv"

with open(tsv_filename, 'w') as tsv_file:
    for row in result:
        tsv_file.write("\t".join(row) + "\n")

print(f"Data saved to {tsv_filename}")
```

Comment: Do I have to post my attempt code

Comment: @Umar, can you show some effort and format properly your input & output ?  What's the input's type by the way ? Also, can you explain why `K03043` should have `Genetic Information Processing, Transcription, RNA polymerase|Metabolism, Carbohydrate metabolism, Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis` in the `metadata_KEGG_Pathways` ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I corrected, input data is in hirarchy as I posted,

Comment: Thanks for amending but what's the type of your input ? a `.txt` file or what ?

Comment: its .keg similar to txt ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to check the [`DBGETEntryParser`](https://pythonhosted.org/Orange-Bioinformatics/reference/kegg.html#orangecontrib.bio.kegg.entry.parser.DBGETEntryParser) from [Orange Bioinformatics](https://pythonhosted.org/Orange-Bioinformatics/index.html) that handles KEGG files. Otherwise, if you're tempted to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) with some regex help, you can try this :

```
import re

with open("file.keg") as f:
    pat = r"^([A-D]) *(\S+)\s*(.+?)\s*(\[.+\])?(?=$)"
    data = re.findall(pat, f.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)  regex101-demo
```

```
import pandas as pd

tmp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["section", "name", "attribute", "path"])
mA = tmp["section"].eq("A"); mD = tmp["section"].eq("D")
df = tmp.assign(entry= tmp["attribute"].where(mA).ffill()).loc[~mA]

parents = (df["entry"].str.cat(df["attribute"].groupby(
        mD.ne(mD.shift()).cumsum(), sort=False)
            .transform(", ".join).where(~mD).ffill(), sep=", ")
            .rename("parents"))

edges = df[["name"]].join(parents).loc[mD, ["parents", "name"]]

out = (df.join(parents).loc[mD].assign(metadata_KEGG_Pathways=
        lambda x: x["attribute"].str.cat(x["path"], sep=" "))
           .groupby("name", sort=False, as_index=False).agg(
               metadata_KEGG_Description=("metadata_KEGG_Pathways", "first"),
               metadata_KEGG_Pathways=("parents", "|".join)))

# out.to_csv("file.tsv", sep="\t", index=False) # uncomment to make a `.tsv`
```

Output (*in a tabular format*) :

| name | metadata_KEGG_Description | metadata_KEGG_Pathways |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K00844 | HK; hexokinase [EC:2.7.1.1] | Metabolism, Carbohydrate metabolism, Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis |
| K12407 | GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2] | Metabolism, Carbohydrate metabolism, Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis |
| K00001 | E1.1.1.1, adh; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1] | Metabolism, Carbohydrate metabolism, Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis|Metabolism, Lipid metabolism, Fatty acid degradation |
| K03043 | rpoB; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta [EC:2.7.7.6] | Genetic Information Processing, Transcription, RNA polymerase |
| K13797 | rpoBC; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta-beta' [EC:2.7.7.6] | Genetic Information Processing, Transcription, RNA polymerase |

A graph visualization with [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx) :

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import chain, pairwise

G = nx.from_edgelist(
    chain.from_iterable(
        [pairwise(vals) for vals in edges.agg(
            ",".join, axis=1).str.split(",").to_numpy()]),
    create_using=nx.DiGraph
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

data = """A09100 Metabolism
B
B  09101 Carbohydrate metabolism
C    00010 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis [PATH:ko00010]
D      K00844  HK; hexokinase [EC:2.7.1.1]
D      K12407  GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]
D      K00001  E1.1.1.1, adh; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1]
B  09103 Lipid metabolism
C    00071 Fatty acid degradation [PATH:ko00071]
D      K00001  E1.1.1.1, adh; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1]
A09120 Genetic Information Processing
B
B  09121 Transcription
C    03020 RNA polymerase [PATH:ko03020]
D      K03043  rpoB; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta [EC:2.7.7.6]
D      K13797  rpoBC; DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta-beta' [EC:2.7.7.6]"""

lines = data.split('\n')

result = []

ko = None
unique_ko_hierarchy = {}

current_hierarchy = []
current_group = None

for line in lines:
    parts = line.strip().split()
    if parts:
        if parts[0].startswith('A'):
            current_group = " ".join(parts[1:])
        elif parts[0].startswith('B'):
            current_hierarchy = [current_group, " ".join(parts[1:])]
        elif parts[0] == 'K':
            ko = parts[1]
            description = " ".join(parts[2:])
            if ko in unique_ko_hierarchy:
                unique_ko_hierarchy[ko]["metadata_KEGG_Pathways"].append(",".join(current_hierarchy))
            else:
                unique_ko_hierarchy[ko] = {
                    "metadata_KEGG_Description": description,
                    "metadata_KEGG_Pathways": [",".join(current_hierarchy)],
                }
        elif parts[0] == 'D' and len(parts) >= 3:
            ko = parts[1]
            description = " ".join(parts[2:])
            if ko in unique_ko_hierarchy:
                unique_ko_hierarchy[ko]["metadata_KEGG_Pathways"].append(",".join(current_hierarchy))
            else:
                unique_ko_hierarchy[ko] = {
                    "metadata_KEGG_Description": description,
                    "metadata_KEGG_Pathways": [",".join(current_hierarchy)],
                }
        else:
            current_hierarchy.append(" ".join(parts[1:]))

# Add the header row
result.append(["KO", "metadata_KEGG_Description", "metadata_KEGG_Pathways"])

for ko, data in unique_ko_hierarchy.items():
    # Remove numeric prefixes and "[PATH:...]" patterns from the pathway string
    pathways = [re.sub(r'\d+\s*', '', pathway.split('[PATH:')[0].strip()) for pathway in data["metadata_KEGG_Pathways"]]
    result.append([ko, data["metadata_KEGG_Description"], "|".join(pathways)])

# Specify the filename for the TSV file
tsv_filename = "output_data.tsv"

with open(tsv_filename, 'w') as tsv_file:
    for row in result:
        tsv_file.write("\t".join(row) + "\n")

print(f"Data saved to {tsv_filename}")
```